# Annotation processor vs bytecode generation

Tags: java

What are the relative merits and demerits of [annotation processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) respect to bytecode generation (e.g. with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/))? Apart from implementation difficulty, why would you prefer one over another?

Since a commenter asked, I'm trying to automatically generate implementations for abstract getter/setter methods, but I would like a more general answer. *I'm not asking what's the better way to generate getters and setters.*

Comment: For solving what problem?

Comment: I was thinking of a general question, with an answer like "I would use ASM rather than annotations when... since...).

Comment: They both are different and I think they complement each other. When you need runtime metadata of your class you can introspect the annotations and there are cases when you need bytecode generation like generation of dynamic proxies.

Answer (score 1):

Some bytecode generator libraries contain support for easy creation of getter/setter variables, which simplifies things significantly - you just import the library classes and write Java code. Some frameworks can even automatically generate getters and setters (along with a whole bunch of other things) based upon a simple annotation on a field.

On the other hand, bytecode generation generally has a runtime performance impact as the new classes are compiled, although that can be mitigated by caching the generated class files.

My experience with annotation processing has not been nearly as pleasant. It generally requires you to configure or even modify your build system so that the annotation processor is executed. In addition, coding an annotation processor can become *very* uncomfortable if you wish to modify a source code file extensively, and apparently there is nowhere near the same framework/library variety as there is for bytecode generation.

My personal favorite, to be honest, is using [Java 7 method handles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) when possible - or just writing the **** getters and setters by hand.

**EDIT:**

The main problem with the annotation processing API is that (as far as I know) it does not support *modifying* code at compile-time. The recommended approach seems to be the generation of independent decorator classes. Sure, that is relatively easy if you use e.g. [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html) but the end result is not nearly the same.

There are some hacks where the original source file is processed to add methods and re-compiled, but even getting the *path* of the source file is almost impossible. There is usually a lot of guesswork involved, with various assumptions about the project structure being made. In addition, the annotation processor essentially maintains a separate source tree for the processed source files.

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) (which I can't believe I forgot to mention before) uses a lot magic of various colors to leverage the annotation processing API to something more usable. It could very well be what you need...

Comment: I did not know about method handles, that's interesting. How can annotation processing become unpleasant? Don't you have only to write java source code? It seems easier than writing bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to use your IDE's accelerators to generate the getters and setters.  That way they are going to be present in the source code.  That will make reading the code easier and avoid potential problems with your debugger.

Creating getters and setters is a bit tedious, but it is not worth adding a whole bunch of complexity (and potential gotchas) to avoid it.  (And if it is *really* too tedious for you,  persuade your boss that you need a "code monkey" to help you.)

Comment: Thanks but getters and setters are only an example; I was not asking what's the best way to generate getters and setters ^^.